# How to join two select sum query statements together

Tags: mysql

I have tried to use different ways to combine 2 select statement queries from MySQL database into one from other similar answered questions off this site but I keep getting syntax errors.  I have tried to use union and join but can't seem to figure out the correct way to do it.  I am trying to display the total sum of column Cost and total sum of Column Clicks.

I am also curious as to how to echo the 2 results side by side in a table?  I get results echoing $test1 (see full code below) and know how to echo that in a table but how would I echo both results and separate both sum totals into two table rows?

Select Statements:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(clicks) AS TotalItemsClicked FROM venue_clicks Where date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AND `username` = '".$_SESSION['username']."'");

$query = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(cost) AS TotalItemsCost FROM venue_clicks Where date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AND `username` = '".$_SESSION['username']."'");
```

I have tried this but I keep getting syntax errors

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(clicks) AS TotalItemsClicked FROM venue_clicks 
Where date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AND `username` = '".$_SESSION['username']."'") 

UNION (also tried JOIN here) 

$query = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(clicks) AS TotalItemsOrdered FROM venue_clicks 
Where date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AND `username` = '".$_SESSION['username']."'");
```

I also tried something like

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(clicks) AS TotalItemsCost AND SUM(Cost) AS TotalItemsCost 
FROM venue_clicks Where date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AND `username` = '".$_SESSION['username']."'");
```

Here is entire code.  I am connecting fine and get results when only running one query. Can anybody help?

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(clicks) AS TotalItemsOrdered FROM venue_clicks 
Where date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AND `username` = '".$_SESSION['username']."'");




$test1 = mysql_fetch_array($query);

echo "$test1[0]";
```

Comment: Note that you're using a long since deprecated API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need either an union or a join, as both refer to both table/view and have the same condition.

```
$query = "select sum(clicks) as TotalItemsClicked, sum(cost) AS TotalItemsCost
from venue_clicks
where date > date_sub(now(), interval 1 month)
and username = '".$_SESSION['username']."'");
```

Also, you should use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [Mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) instead of [deprecated mysql](http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php) functions to query your database.

Comment: Thanks for reply.  I got this from a tutorial I will learn how to change it to PDO or Mysqli.  How do I echo results for both of these?  I am only getting the first result (clicks) in my echo?

Comment: @bg2982 Simply `echo test[0];` and `echo test[1];`

Comment: Thanks for the help.  Now I will try and change this around to Mysqli.